# Serialport nodejs strange character

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I try to receive version of the goto firmware of the celestron nexstar goto system.

I receive some data using serialport library but I receive some strange character, Termite is the only soft that display the good characters.

Here is an example of the data that I receive and the data that Termite display.

Serialport from node.js : ♦§#

Termite : [04][15]#

Here is the code that connect to the mount and display the received data :

```
var telescope = new serial(port.comName, {
   baudRate: 9600,
   stopBits: 1,
   parity: 'none'
});

telescope.on('open', function () {

   telescope.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('Data : ' + data);
   });

   telescope.write('V');

});
```

Is there any way to display the good data ? I search and I think that this is an encoding problem

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How  convert `\x5b\x30\x34\x5d\x5b\x31\x35\x5d\x23` **TO**  `♦§#` ?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that Termite displays control characters (with a few exceptions) in the form of `[xx]` where `xx` is the control character's hex value. However in node, you are implicitly treating the entirety of the incoming data as UTF-8.

You *could* emulate Termite's behavior by checking each byte value and printing the hex value in brackets if it's a control character or writing the character to stdout.

Comment: oh okay it's seems that's a bit complicated :D did I have to write or use another parser (I use the raw parser) ?

Comment: It depends on the kind of data you're dealing with. If it's binary data, then it's best to keep using the raw parser. If it's a shell session or other textual data, then probably the line parser might be better?